# using .htaccess to serve html files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to create cache as this example :

All html files like theses :

```
my_site.com/file_1.html

my_site.com/dir_1/...../dir_n/file_x.html
```

Apache tests if file exists really in :

```
my_site.com/generated/file_1.html

my_site.com/generated/dir1/...../dirn/file_x.html
```

If founds it serves the generated files, 
If it does not found them, it call `index.php/file_1.html`  ,  `index.php/dir1/...../dirn/file_x.html` to serve the content dynamically

this concern only html extensions

How can I do it with .htaccess file?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^generated/.*$
RewriteCond generated/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . /generated/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

That checks only .html file call from an address that does not include /generated/, and if generated/.... filname exists, serves it. should work from what I understood of your hierarchy.

Comment: thank you, but you have not add `RewriteRule`, and how to call index.php with file link parmeter if these files not be found

Comment: Ah yes, last one is a rewrite sorry.

Comment: thank you for correction, but how to use index.php with parameter if the file will not be found

Comment: I don't get you? The rules say : if .html file and does not begins with generated then if generated/<name> exists then serve it. QueryString will be appended automatically.